# SQL Server - Linked Server error - Could not connect to server XYZ because

Tags: sql-server-2012, linked-server, transactional-replication

Server being used: SQL Server 2012 SP3 
I just received a strange error (strange because it worked earlier)

```
could not connect to server LNK_SRV because sa is not defined as a remote login
```

[image]
Not sure why we are receiving the error.

The sys.servers says is_linked = 0 for LNK_SRV - not sure why.
The following returns results

```
select top 10 * from LNK_SRV.DBName.dbo.TblName
```

But the procedures are failing

```
exec LNK_SRV.DBName.dbo.ProcName
```

It was working fine before we dropped the linked server and re-added it.
Also, the LNK_SRV is being used as for replication as well.

Note: I am aware sa is bad. It will be taken care soon.

Comment: On the Linked Server Property page under the Server Options, what is the value of RPC?

Comment: You are impersonating the login.. check if the login that you are impersonating has access to remote server.

Comment: @ScottHodgin, RPC is True

Comment: @Kin yes, the login has access to remote server. I can query all the SELECT's. Only issue is with EXEC <<procedure>>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The linked server was also used for replication. 
The order of Subscribe and Create linked server was the issue.

Reproduce the error:
1.  Drop the subscription 
2.  Drop the linked server
3.  Configure the Subscription first
4.  Linked Server next 
5.  Testing 
- a.    Select will return results
- b.    Exec proc result in error

---

Fix:
1.  Drop the subscription
2.  Drop the Linked Server
3.  Create the Linked Server first
4.  Configure the Subscription next
5.  Testing
- a.    Select will return results
- b.    Exec proc will succeed

Also, executing the following on Linked Server worked as well.

```
--Run this statement on LNK_SRVR
exec sp_AddRemoteLogin 'CurrServer','sa'
```

Comment: I run the script and it solve my problem.
exec sp_AddRemoteLogin 'CurrServer','sa'

Comment: I solved the problem with the statement alone without dropping anything.  So if CurrServer -> LNK_SRV means you are connecting from CurrServer to LNK_SRV, your statement basically maps all login connecting from CurrServer to the sa account on LNK_SRV so that it has permission to execute a stored procedure.  Another way you can solve this is to check the login you used on "Be made using this security context" make sure that is using an acocunt that has permission to everything

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation for [sys.servers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-servers-transact-sql), **is_linked**:

> 0 = Is an old-style server added by using sp_addserver, with different
>   RPC and distributed-transaction behavior.
>
> 1 = Standard linked server.

The fact that your linked server is returning 0 for is_linked indicates that the linked server was created using the old-style `sp_addserver` (which is not recommended).

I'd suggest creating a 'new' linked server (for testing purposes) by either scripting an existing one that was NOT created using `sp_addserver` or creating a new linked server from SSMS GUI.  Make sure you visit the Security page of the newly created linked server and adjust as necessary.

Try using the new linked server to execute the remote stored procedure and also normal selects, etc.  If that works, then drop the current linked server that's failing and replace it with the new one that works.

Answer (score 0):

This seems a tricky error. As per the question, you are able to do `SELECT` but getting an error message for the `exec`. You may try the below options if they are not already taken care of:

1. Enable DTC (Distributed Transaction coordinator) on the servers.
2. Enable RPC out and RPC in in Linked server properties.

**DTC** is used by the SQL server when two or more machines are involved and wants to make a distributed transactions between them. More information can be found at the below links.

[MSDN Blog for DTC](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cindygross/2010/10/18/do-i-need-dtc-for-my-sql-server/)

[Microsoft DOCs for Distributed Transaction Syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/begin-distributed-transaction-transact-sql)

[How to enable DTC option on SQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7694/how-do-i-enable-msdtc-on-sql-server): There is an helpful answer provided by "Shiv Sing" on stack overflow.

To **enable RPC in and out**, open the properties window of linked server in SQL Server Management Studio. Select `Server Options`, there you will find RPC and RPC out parameters. Mark them as yes.

Once this is done, try executing the same command in below format.

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON
BEGIN DISTRIBUTED TRANSACTION
EXEC LNK_SRV.DBName.dbo.ProcName
COMMIT TRAN
SET XACT_ABORT OFF
```